# ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive at runtime

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I don't know why I get this error message. This is my html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="insert" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(insert.value)">

            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
                <div class="ui-g-5 ui-g-offset-1  ui-md-4 ui-md-offset-1 ui-lg-4 ui-lg-offset-1">
                    <span >name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4 ui-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="name_student" formControlName="name_student" />
                </div>
            </div>
...
</form>
```

In y .ts I do:

```
  insert: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    //gestione degli errori dopo il submit
    this.insert= this.fb.group({
      'name_student': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

I obtain:

```
ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using       formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You cannot mix template based forms (`ngModel`) with reactive forms (`formControlName`). Choose one, or the other.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form [formGroup]="insert" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(insert.value)">

            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12">
                <div class="ui-g-5 ui-g-offset-1  ui-md-4 ui-md-offset-1 ui-lg-4 ui-lg-offset-1">
                    <span >name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4 ui-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="name_student" formControlName="name_student" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true />
                </div>
            </div>
...
</form>
```

you should put `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true`

Comment: Amin, NOT put in the same input [(ngModel)] and formControlName. You need use  `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}` if inside a ReactiveForm, you has a input that **not** belong to the formGroup. Imagine you want has a "checkbox" that **not** belong to the formGroup, you can mannage this for e.g. disabled some formControl that yes belong to the formGroup, or has a select that "fill" some formControl (typical you has a list of countries that fill a prefix of telephone. You're not interesting in the country, just in the prefix, so your formGroup has not a field "country")

Comment: @Eliseo didn't attention to code more. so it means if we use one of them ` [(ngModel)]` or   `FormControlName` the error will disappear ?

Comment: @Admin, you choose if you want to use ReactiveForms o TemplateDriven Form. there are two **differents** ways to manage data. If use ReactiveForm you use [formGroup], formControlName, ..., and if you choose Template driven Form you use [(ngModel)], ngForm..., see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: @Eliseo  Yeah,great.I will read about. I've never been admin cuz i'm amin ;)